# How would you implement Controller in Javascript? (inside of self-made MVC)

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

**I want to implement [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern in JavaScript, but I have a problem with Controller implementation.**

MVC concepts are clear to me. I understand how MVC works. I don't think that events is appropriate way build a Controller. And there are a lot of dependences because of edition of the event in JavaScript.
I would like to see some small example of implementation of MVC Controller in JavaScript.

**p.s.** I want to implement MVC pattern by using only JavaScript, but I don't want to use any MVC open-source frameworks.

**p.s.** I don't want you to do my homework, but I really don't understand how to imprelent Controller in JavaScript.

Comment: Aren't controllers a **server** concept?  You could do it in Node.JS on a server and stay with Javascript, but controllers in a browser don't make much sense.

Comment: As you can see - here is she talking about Javascript. And I think it's about client Javascript. So it's not about server

Comment: Maybe you could look at how existing frameworks do it.

Comment: @Juhana - there Is more that 40 Javascript MVC frameworks, but the problem is that if you don't know how they works, you are not a professional programmer..

Comment: @Juhana - I saw a lot of programmers who new a lot of frameworks, but when those frameworks was broken - they doesn't know what to do. I don't think that "knowledge of frameworks" === "knowledge of language" && "knowledge of frameworks" === "knowledge of patterns". Dose this make sense to you?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The OP asked how to implement a controller in an MVC framework. I suggested that he could solve his problem by looking at how existing frameworks implement controllers.

Comment: Do you always depend on someone? You can just simply learn MVC patter - this way you don't need to look at any framework, you can implement it yourself. It's not hard as it looks like, more over you can create your own Pattern :) Just give it a try - it's really intresting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basicly MVC is based apon the Observer pattern (and controller is also)

How you can implement Observer inside of Javascript?

```
function Observer() {
    var subscribers = [];
    return {
        subscribe: function(eventName, object) {
            subscribers.push({ event: eventName, target: object });
        },
        unsubscribe: function(object) {
            var indexToDelete = subscribers.indexOf(object);
            subscribers.splice(indexToDelete, 1);
        },
        trigger: function(eventName, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5) {
            for (var i = 0; i < subscribers.lenght; i++) {
                if (subscribers[i].event == eventName) {
                    //target object must implement this function
                    subscribers[i].target[eventName](p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And how you can use it?

```
var model = { 
    fireChangesInsideOfModel: function(p1){ 
        //do some model update logic here
    } 
}
var controller = Observer();
    controller.subscribe("fireChangesInsideOfModel", model);

controller.trigger("fireChangesInsideOfModel", 11231); // 11231 - is an example of a parameter
```

Hope this helps you..